# How to add a button and overlay it on my Google map fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, button, google-api

So I have myself a `GoogleMap` using my API key. I'm able to find my location, but when opened the app does not have any buttons. If I try to click and drag any buttons in via the android design layout, it doesn't allow this.

This is what my `activity_maps.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

When looking at the android phone view beside it, it just says  and I am unsure how to add a button on top of this map, or even below it if possible.
I am aware of `ConstraintLayout` and `FrameLayout`, but when adding additional code I just get 'multiple roots error'and have been unable to achieve what I am looking for.

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example with constraint layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"

        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simpler solution is to set an overlay in front of your map using `FrameLayout`or `RelativeLayout`and treating them as regular buttons in your activity. You should declare your layers in back to front order, e.g., map before buttons, Try the following layout and see if it works for you

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapActivity" >

        <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"  
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:padding="4dp" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your fragment with `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout` and then set additional buttons.

Instead of this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

It should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          tools:context=".MapsActivity"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    tools:text="Button one"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    tools:text="Button two"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is just example with `RelativeLayout`.